# Symfony - Approach to CollectionType Field with mulitple junction tables

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, entity, symfony-forms

I'm relative new to symfony, and now i need to replicate a form that allready exists in the current application, but now in an symfony way.

The application weighs values relative to the answer of a (dynamic) number of questions.

The weighting factor is allso depending on a (dynamic) number of factors.

Trying to make it clear with the following image:

**Objective:**
[Entity form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3K9va.png)

**Relations currently set up:**

Entity:

Entity -- oneToMany -> EntityOptionValues

EntityOptionValues: (to store the actual chosen optionvalues)

EntityOptionValues -- ManyToOne -> Entity

EntityOptionValues -- ManyToMany -> OptionValue

OptionValue:

OptionValue -- ManyToMany -> EntityOptionValues

OptionValue -- ManyToOne -> optionsGroup

optionsGroup:

optionsGroup -- oneToMany -> OptionValue

optionsGroup -- ManyToMany -> Group

Group:

Group -- oneToMany -> optionsGroup

**Solution**(in progress)

I am considering to make a from through the formbuilder with an "CollectionType Field" .
Is this the right way to go, or should I go for an onther approach?

And if so could you please explain why your solution should be the way to go.

Any help is welcome, thanks in advance

*** EDIT ***
I'll make the test project available in github, working on that right now.

*** EDIT ***

I started this testcode with a fresh symfony installation. I have created a GIT repository for this test project

You can find it [here](https://github.com/toosrimpeldoos/formtest).

Now I need to build the form.

But what wouldbe te right way to go from here?

Post wil be updated as soon I got it there.

**For the community:**

I will post and update this Question along the way, so other users can use those

Comment: Yes use collectionType to do this

Comment: Thnks for your reply, I'll dive into that

Comment: I made a bare symfony procject and posted it to github, to @DOZ and all others, Now I have to create that specific form. 

Please guide me here.